# Is there a more compact way of checking if a number is within a range?

Tags: javascript, range, comparison

I want to be able to test whether a value is within a number range. This is my current code:

```
if ((year < 2099) && (year > 1990)){
    return 'good stuff';
}
```

Is there a simpler way to do this? For example, is there something like this?

```
if (1990 < year < 2099){
    return 'good stuff';
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In many languages, the second way will be evaluated from left to right incorrectly with regard to what you want.

In C, for instance, `1990 < year` will evaluate to 0 or 1, which then becomes `1 < 2099`, which is always true, of course.

Javascript is a quite similar to C: `1990 < year` returns `true` or `false`, and those boolean expressions seem to numerically compare equal to 0 and 1 respectively.

But in C#, it won't even compile, giving you the error:

> error CS0019: Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'

You get a similar error from Ruby, while Haskell tells you that you cannot use `<`  twice in the same infix expression.

Off the top of my head, Python is the only language that I'm sure handles the "between" setup that way:

```
>>> year = 5
>>> 1990 < year < 2099
False
>>> year = 2000
>>> 1990 < year < 2099
True
```

The bottom line is that the first way `(x < y && y < z)` is always your safest bet.

Comment: OK, I'd meant in javascript, sorry. I guess the two statements with && is the only way?

Answer (score 11):

You could make your own method:

```
// jquery
$(function() {
    var myNumber = 100;
    try {
        if (myNumber.isBetween(50, 150)) 
            alert(myNumber + " is between 50 and 100.");
        else 
            alert(myNumber + " is not between 50 and 100.");
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e.message());
    }

});

// js prototype
if (typeof(Number.prototype.isBetween) === "undefined") {
    Number.prototype.isBetween = function(min, max, notBoundaries) {
        var between = false;
        if (notBoundaries) {
            if ((this < max) && (this > min)) between = true;
            alert('notBoundaries');
        } else {
            if ((this <= max) && (this >= min)) between = true;
            alert('Boundaries');
        }
        alert('here');
        return between;
    }
}
```

hope this helps.

Max

Answer (score 2):

The fast and simple way to make this is to create a function like this:

```
function inRange(n, nStart, nEnd)
{
    if(n>=nStart && n<=nEnd) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Then use that as follows:

```
inRange(500, 200, 1000) => this return true;
```

Or like this:

```
inRange(199, 200, 1000) => this return false;
```

Comment: This code is better: 

return n>=nStart && n<=nEnd;

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the boolean operator, you could always use nested if statements:

```
if (1990 < year)
{
    if( year < 2099)
        return 'good stuff';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From a similar solution here: http://indisnip.wordpress.com/2010/08/26/quicktip-check-if-a-number-is-between-two-numbers/

```
$.fn.between = function(a,b){
    return (a < b ? this[0] >= a && this[0] <= b : this[0] >= b && this[0] <= a);
}
```

Comment: -1. You've added this to prototype of jQuery objects, when it is intended to be added to the prototype of `Number`, as explained in the link you've provided. Not only does this not relate to the OP's question, but it's a nonsensical thing to do.

Comment: Why does this not relate? The OP asked for a jquery solution, the link describes a native js solution. Everything in jquery is an object, hence the object prototype. Why is it nonsensical? Agreed, it requires that the value of the object be referenced, rather than the object itself (which I have corrected) but I hardly think that makes it nonsensical... working example: http://jsfiddle.net/xq4NE/

Comment: Hmm. Following your modifications, I'll concede it's no longer nonsense. It's still not something I'd do though; there's no reason that the jQuery solution is better than the one you linked to, and as far as I know, calling jQuery on numbers (you'd need to do something like `$(4).between(3,5)` isn't something people do done (reasonably enough, since most of the methods of a jQuery object are specific to DOM elements); you're breaking from normal jQuery patterns needlessly, and forcing a jQuery solution to something that doesn't need it. http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif

Comment: If the OP is using straight numeric data in his script, then you're right; the number prototype would be better. But what if he gets his number from an input? Change this[0] to this.val()... Would you do it then?